# How to install ImageMagick with XAMPP on Mac OS X Lion 10.7

Tags: php, imagemagick, osx-lion, xampp, imagick

Okay, i spent hours to figure this out. I just want to share it out there.

**What works**
1. follow this tutorial
http://mikepuchol.com/2010/08/26/getting-mamp-1-9-to-work-with-image-magick-imagick-so-and-other-flora/

Note: STEP 2 is rather important on that tutorial
Because that tutorial is targetting MAMP platform; for XAMPP imagick.so to
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/

**What doesnt work**
1. i tried homebrew that provides 32bit ImageMagick binary only, that clashed with compiled imagick

Comment: This is not the correct format for a self-answered question on SO. Please post the solution as an answer to your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking